# How To Generate HTML Table from Curl Response?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Hello How To Generate HTML Table from Curl Response ?

`

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=SAW&destination=AYT&depart_date=2022-10-26&return_date=2022-10-27&currency=usd",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-access-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
  print_r($json);
}

?>



<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($data[0]["data"]);$i++) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[0]['data'][$i]['price'] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[0]['data'][$i]['airline'] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[0]['data'][$i]['flight_number'] . '</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
}?>
```

`
Curl Output :

Array
(
[success] => 1
[data] => Array
(
[AYT] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[price] => 145
[airline] => PC
[flight_number] => 4000
[departure_at] => 2022-10-26T18:10:00+03:00
[return_at] => 2022-10-27T05:55:00+03:00
[expires_at] => 2022-10-26T00:54:23Z
)

```
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 389
                        [airline] => PC
                        [flight_number] => 1910
                        [departure_at] => 2022-10-26T06:20:00+03:00
                        [return_at] => 2022-10-27T05:55:00+03:00
                        [expires_at] => 2022-10-26T00:54:23Z
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 349
                        [airline] => PC
                        [flight_number] => 2666
                        [departure_at] => 2022-10-26T11:40:00+03:00
                        [return_at] => 2022-10-27T05:55:00+03:00
                        [expires_at] => 2022-10-26T00:54:23Z
                    )

            )

    )

[currency] => usd
```

)

I want to export curl output to html table, but I'm getting an error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

- From above code you did not declared any variable like `$data`
- comment  print_r($json);
- This might help.

```php
<?php
    foreach ($json['data'] as $key=>$value){
       if(is_array($value)){
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach($value as $skey=>$svalue){
            echo "<td>$svalue</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>";
       }
    }
?>
```

Comment: no bro update is not working!